# DataTables In Async Methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I have created some async methods and have been adding records to a dataTable in those methods, and then bulk copying the dataTable after the async methods are done. I've found now that dataTables are not thread-safe, and that is the source of my problem, as I was noticing one or two records not actually getting inserted. I have something like this:

```
    private async void yea()
    {
        DataTable t = new DataTable();      
        //Fill the data table with its columns
        IEnumerable<Task<string>> results = items.Select(q => AsyncFunction(q.id, t));
        Task<string[]> allTasks = Task.WhenAll(results);
        string[] allResults = await results;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                bc.BatchSize = 1000;
                bc.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                bc.WriteToServer(t);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> AsyncFunction(int id, DataTable t)
    {
        //await another Async function
        DataRow dr = t.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = id;
        //Many More columns
        t.Rows.Add(dr);
        return "success";
    }
```

Like I said my problem is that the bulk copy often misses a few records. How can I bulk copy all of the records without losing them to non-thread safe calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do one datatable per task, when you go to upload you can concat them all together again, your code is not complete (for example where does `Result` come from and how is it used) but here is the basics of how you can do it and you will need to adjust to your code.

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
//Fill the data table with its columns
IEnumerable<Task<Result>> results = items.Select(q => AsyncFunction(q.id, t);

Task<NewResult[]> allTasks = Task.WhenAll(results); //This line is unnecessary with the code available.

NewResult[] allResults = await results;


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
    {
        bc.BatchSize = 1000;
        bc.DestinationTableName = tableName;

        //Joins all of the data rows from all of the generated tables in to a single array.
        DataRow[] allRows = allResults.SelectMany(a=>a.LocalDataTable.AsEnumerable().ToArray();

        bc.WriteToServer(allRows);
    }
}


public async Task<NewResult> AsyncFunction(int id, DataTable template)
{
    DataTable localDataTable = template.Clone(); //DataTable is thread safe for read operations like .Clone()        

    //Do some stuff
    DataRow dr = t.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = id
    //Many More columns
    t.Rows.Add(dr);

    //Be sure you have a "await" somewhere in that removed section or else this code will not be multi-threaded.

    return new NewResult("success", localDataTable);    
}
```

You could also call `.CreateDataReader()` on each class and then write a wrapper that would concatenate multiple `IDataReaders` together so you don't need to allocate the extra `DataRow[]` or just call `SqlBulkCopy` multiple times, once for each data table.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mutate the `DataTable` within the async method.  Have the async method compute the row, return it, and then add all of the rows once you have the results:

```
foreach(var row in await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(q => AsyncFunction(q.id, t))
    t.Rows.Add(row);
```